# Selenium Firefox driver window isn't closed when an exception raises

Tags: selenium, firefox, driver

So lets assume I have some function using FirefoxDriver:

```py
    def init_firefox():
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        ...
```

And during performing this function there might be an exception raised by some reason. I catch it by this way:

```py
    try:
        init_firefox()
    except Exception:
        print('Exception raised!')
```

The issue I've encountered is that when init_firefox really raises an exception, Firefox window isn't closed and persists in RAM. Is there a way to close this single window without closing other ones?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to close the window you want, The only thing you need in this case is for the driver to be in **that specific window** to be closed !!

This is a bit explanation on how to do so!!
I tested this code with `chromedriver` i already have in my machine

```
# x refers to the window you want to switch to x = 1 or 2 ..  
window_to_close = driver.window_handles[x]
driver.switch_to.window(window_to_close)
driver.close()
```